Dart package layout for static data files
My project uses a single large text file with a collection of English words. This file should never be changed by code, only read from.
Is there a standard location in the file structure for a file like this?
Flutter uses the /assets folder, but my project is in pure Dart.
I have also seen people use a /data folder but I can't find any official documentation for this.
I checked out the Dart package layout conventions but there is no mention of static data files, unless I missed something.
